# Error fatal : Error no detectado: llamada a una función miembro prepare () en nulo

Tags: php, sql, mvc

Buenas estoy intentando hacer una consulta mvc pero me da el siguiente error:
**Error fatal : Error no detectado: llamada a una función miembro prepare () en nulo en C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ mvc_gymArtCopia \ Libraries \ Core \ Mysql.php: 19 Seguimiento de pila: # 0 C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ mvc_gymArtCopia \ Models \ clientesModel.php (15): Mysql-> select_all ('SELECT * FROM c ...') # 1 C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ mvc_gymArtCopia \ Controllers \ Clientes.php (16): clientesModel-> getClients () # 2 C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ mvc_gymArtCopia \ Libraries \ Core \ Load.php (10): Clientes-> home ('') # 3 C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ mvc_gymArtCopia \ index.php (29): require_once (' C: \ xampp \ htdocs ... ') # 4 {main} lanzado en C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ mvc_gymArtCopia \ Libraries \ Core \ Mysql.php en la línea 19**

me gustaría saber por que es, creo que tiene que ser por algo de la conexión por que la sentencia y demás creo que esta bien

mis archivos son:

**mysql.php**

```
class Mysql extends Conexion {

private $conexion;
private $strquery;
private $arrvalues;

function __construct()
{
    $this->conexion = new Conexion();
    $this->conexion = $this->conexion->conect();
}

//devuelve todos los registros
public function select_all(string $query) {
    $this->strquery = $query;
    
    $result = $this->conexion->prepare($this->strquery);
    $result->execute();
    $data = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $data;
}
```

**conexion.php**

```
class Conexion {

private $connect;

public function __construct()
{
    $conecting= "mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME.";.DB_CHARSET.";
    try {
        $this->conect = new PDO($conecting,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
        $this->conect ->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        // echo "COnexion exitosa";
    }catch(PDOException $e) {
        $this->conect ="Error de conexion";
        print "¡Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
        // die();
    }
  }

public function conect(){
    return $this->connect;
}   

}
```

**Models/clientesModel.php**

```
 class clientesModel extends Mysql
{
// public $model;

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function getClients()
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM clientes";
    $viewClient = $this->select_all($sql);
    return $viewClient;
}
```

**Controllers/Clientes.php**

```
class Clientes extends Controllers
{

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function home()
{
    // $data['page_id'] = 1;
    $data['tag_page'] = "GymArt";
    $data['page_title'] = "Clientes";
    $data['clientes'] = $this->verUsuarios();

    $this->views->getView($this, "clientes", $data);
}

    public function verUsuarios()
{
    $data = $this->model->getClients();
    print_r($data);
}
```

Comment: En el constructor de la clase `Mysql` comenta esta línea: `$this->conexion = $this->conexion->conect();` No tiene sentido esa llamada, porque la conexión se crearía en el constructor de la clase `Conexion`, de la cual extiende `Mysql`, por tanto, deberías poder usar a `conexion` directamente. De todos modos la clase `Conexion` está organizada de un modo confuso en ese sentido.

Comment: @A.Cedano por que esta de modo confuso?

Comment: Porque tienes un método `connect()` que realmente no conecta, pues la conexión se crea en el constructor de la clase. Si dedicas un método a conectar, entonces significa que la acción de ese verbo debe ocurrir en ese método. Desde el punto de vista de POO tu método actual debería llamarse `setConnection()`, porque es lo que ahí ocurre, solo que tampoco tendría sentido hacer eso. [Mira este ejemplo](https://github.com/padrecedano/PHP-PDO/blob/master/DbPDO.class.php) quizá la clase sería más clara si organizas de ese modo.

Comment: He intentando adaptar eso a mi archivo conexión ya ya no me sale el error el problema que me sale este error **C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ mvc_gymArtCopia \ Views \ Clientes \ clientes.php: 15: null** @A.Cedano

Comment: ¿Qué hay en la línea 15 de `clientes.php`?

Comment: $datos =$data["clientes"] ;
 var_dump($datos); estaba intentado meter en una variable el $data("clientes) del controlador @A.Cedano

Comment: Depura primero `var_dump($data);`

Comment: Me recoge todo lo demas pero no me recoge clientes me da un null @A.Cedano

Comment: Dime qué muestra el `var_dump($data);` ¿? Cuando un dato falle depúralo globalmente, no una parte de él.

Comment: array  (size = 5) 
  'page_id' =>  int  1 
  'tag_page' =>  string  'GymArt'  (length = 6) 
  'page_title' = >  string  'Clientes'  (length = 8) 
  'page_content' =>  string  'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Et, quis. Perspiciatis repellat perferendis accusamus, ea natus id omnis, ratione alias quo dolore tempore dicta cum aliquid corrupti enim deserunt voluptas.  (longitud = 215) 
  'clientes' =>  null @A.Cedano

Comment: Sí como dices tienes esto en la línea del null: `$datos =$data["clientes"] ;` OBSERVA bien que la clave `clientes` de $data es `null`. Debes entonces revisar a qué se debe que cuando obtienes $data ese valor viene como null

Comment: He actualizado mis archivos en el cuerpo de la pregunta puede  ser que no este llamando bien en el controlador en la funcion verUsuarios a la funcion **getClients** del modelo? y por eso me de null?@A.Cedano

Comment: ¿Acaso la tabla `clientes` tiene una columna llamada `clientes`?  El fetch que haces en `select_all` estaría creando un array asociativo donde las claves serían los nombres de columna y cada valor serían los valores de las mismas. Revisa entonces en la tabla por qué el valor de la columna `clientes` es null

Comment: Ya he podido solucionarlo muchas gracias :) @A.Cedano